# iOS template for c# is not there in visual studio mac(professional)

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

iOS c# template is not vissible in visual studio mac 2022. I have tried un-installing and re-installing the software using mac installer. Tried to get the template via terminal using "dotnet workload install ios", the package console will display "installing" but the template is not getting installed as well.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oiiad.png). My xcode version is 15.2 and the visual studio version is 17.6.8 .

1. I had tried un-installing the software and re-installing it again.
2. Tried to install via terminal using the cmd "dotnet install workload ios".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ8lQ.png). The package console will display "installing" but the tempalte will not get installed and finally error cmd will get displayed as mentioned in the  screenshot.
3. During the installation i had made sure that all the dependencies are installed.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTt2q.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K25r6.png)

Comment: 5he screenshot you posted shows **five** Xamarin iOS templates.  What **specifically** do you think is missing?

Comment: FYI: VS for mac is going away soon. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-for-mac-retirement-announcement/

Comment: A c# section was there was there for android project similarly  it should be there for iOS as well.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Xcode on your Mac? During the VS for Mac installing process, did you check the iOS as the available workload? Specifically, you can refer to the [Install Visual Studio for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation?view=vsmac-2022).

Comment: My xcode version is 15.2, visual studio professional version is 17.6.8 and i had installed .net, xamarin-ios,android, macOs cocoa during the initial installation phase

Comment: Did you try to use another VS version? such as VS Preview.